# Can i use column number instead of column name in where condition of a select query in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

can we use column number instead of column name in where condition of a select  query in SQL Server 2005 so that even if the column name is so long.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` can inadvertently change the default order of columns. That means that a query that used to run perfectly well will stop working after some maintenance. Use column names.

Answer (score 5):

no you cannot directly, just drag the column name you want from the object explorer into your query...you don't need to type it

Hit F8, this will open Object Browser.
Navigate to DatabaseName/TableName/Columns.
Click on the column folder and drag the column folder into the Code Window.
Upon release you will see that all the column names are in the Code Window.

Another option would be (and I do not recommend this )

you would need to use dynamic SQL and do a lookup in information_schema.columns and look for ordinal_position to get the column number. If you need column 5 you would get ordinal_position  5 to grab the column name. this however is messy

Comment: here is my query select * from table_name where somecolumn=5

here i get the column name dynamically so insted so insted of using column name can i use the column number

Comment: no you cannot like that, you would need to use dynamic SQL and do a lookup in information_schema.columns and look for ordinal_position to get the column number

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't, but you can create an inline view instead:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  Supercalifragilisticexpialidociousness AS s
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   s = 1
```

`SQL Server` is smart enough to push the predicate into the view so it won't hurt performance.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you could it would be asking for trouble.

Imagine, a few months later, you add a column to the SELECT clause and forget/overlook the matching WHERE clause...

Answer (score 3):

This is just an all around bad idea. Use the column name no matter how long it is. Honestly, this is a maintenance nightmare and you will regret doing this.

And really try to avoid using dynamic SQL; it is generally a poor practice.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this.  Even if you could, it would be considered bad practice.  Column names are far more readable than numbers, no matter how long the column names are (considering that column name limit is 128 chars in MS SQL)

Answer (score 2):

> here is my query **select * from
>   table_name where somecolumn=5** here i
>   get the column name dynamically so
>   insted so insted of using column name
>   can i use the column number

From your comment I guess you are trying to query by getting a column name dynamically. You can do this by fetching the column names into a variable and the creating a dynamic SQL query.

```
declare @colname varchar(128)
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @colname = 'Server'
set @sql = 'select * from Jobs where '+@colname+'='+'''S02AAPEXP01'''
exec (@sql)
```

Beats me why you would want to do this, though!!!

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this for a WHERE clause. **You CAN, however, do this for an ORDER BY clause.**   I use it all the time for ad-hoc queries where I don't want to have to re-type a complicated function in the ORDER BY:

```
SELECT ServerCode, Count(*) as Databases 
FROM DatabaseList 
GROUP BY ServerCode 
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

or

```
SELECT EventCode, EndTime, Convert(Varchar(50),TextData) as QueryName, CPU, READS
FROM TraceData
ORDER BY 3
```

Now, would I put it in a production stored proc? Probably not.

Comment: I also do the same "ORDER BY N" shortcut all the time in quickie development/testing queries, but they want to do it in the WHERE and not the ORDER BY.  That syntax does not work in the WHERE, only the ORDER BY

Comment: @BradC - How about in the TOP/OFFSET FETCH part of the SQL - can we use the columnnumber there? As these are executed after the select and orderby logically we should be able to isnnt it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hard time remembering the column names, there are some SQL intellisense programs out there, I know RedGate offers one.

[SqL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm)

SQL 2008 finally comes with Intellisense.

Comment: But SQL 2008 Intellisense only works on SQL 2008 databases, sadly :[

Answer (score 0):

Here are two tips for quickly selecting multiple column names, both which seem to be rarely known/used by SQL Server developers.

1 - Highlight your table name in Query Analyzer (double-click it). Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>. You will see tons of info about the table, among it the column names. Drag to select one or more column names, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>, to paste them into your query. This is also a good way to see what indexes and constraints are on the table.

2 - From Object Explorer, right-click on your table and select *Script Table as/SELECT To/Clipboard*. Then paste the results into your query and remove the parts you don't need.