# Is there any good reason to use numbers of column instead of names?

Tags: sql

I saw some code of people where they were used number of columns instead of names.

As i found out in old question:
[Can i use column number instead of column name in where condition of a select query in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063739/can-i-use-column-number-instead-of-column-name-in-where-condition-of-a-select-qu)

There were not any good oppinions about this type of selecting instead of one with inline view approach.

It's few years later now.

Do you know any good reason to use number of columns instead of column names?

I would like to be assured that selecting columns by names instead number of column is the best approach in every case. Second option is to learn new specific approaches which shows usefulness of numbering columns during selection.

Comment: The column ordinal changes when you perform maintenance of the table. That means a query that used to run perfectly well may stop working after some maintenance. Use column names and sleep well at night.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no good reason to refer to a column by its ordinal position instead of its name.

Nothing has changed that since the question you linked to was answered.

Some implementations of SQL allow the ordinal to refer to a column in the `ORDER BY` clause, but this is actually deprecated. It is removed in the ANSI/ISO SQL standard, and it is discouraged in most implementations.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html:

> Use of column positions is deprecated because the syntax has been removed from the SQL standard.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#best-practices

> Avoid specifying integers in the ORDER BY clause as positional representations of the columns in the select list. For example, although a statement such as SELECT ProductID, Name FROM Production.Production ORDER BY 2 is valid, the statement is not as easily understood by others compared with specifying the actual column name. In addition, changes to the select list, such as changing the column order or adding new columns, requires modifying the ORDER BY clause in order to avoid unexpected results.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html

> The ordinal number refers to the ordinal (left-to-right) position of the output column. This feature makes it possible to define an ordering on the basis of a column that does not have a unique name. This is never absolutely necessary because it is always possible to assign a name to an output column using the AS clause.

Answer (score 0):

If some of the group by condition are derived columns, NOT all DB query engines (such as Presto) will accept name alias of derived columns in the same select clause. In that case, using the column number is a more straight-forward approach compared to another level of nested query to get name alias recognized by DB query engines.

Using column number for derived columns in group by condition

```
SELECT
   name,
   case 
        when age>=18 then 'adult'
        else 'kid'
   end as customer_type,
   count(1) as num_orders
from
   orders
group by 1,2
```